# nuget packages for arm architecture for asp.net-5

Tags: asp.net-core, coreclr

Just like for any other architecture there should be package fro asp.net-5 coreclr like dnx-coreclr-linux-arm for arm arch.

There are already packages for other architectures:
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=dnx-coreclr

I know that in beta7 there was some effort done to enable arm compilation:
https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/pull/2039

Does anyone knows if there any plans for releasing them via nuget? This would enable dev for raspberry pi or home mini pc's like qnap 2xx series.

Comment: Note that the available DNX ARM builds are for Windows 10 IoT Core (e.g. Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows) and not for ARM based Linux systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARM support isn't being shipped as part of any planned release. It's something that's available on the ci feed though.

Comment: https://myget.org/F/aspnetlitedev/api/v2 in case you don't know what the CI feed is

Comment: That url seems to be broken and I can't find anything that has replaced it. What site do I need to watch to know if and when dnx for arm is released/planned?