# DNX on Lego Mindstorms

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, lego-mindstorms

I am not familiar with ARM development but I am wondering would it be possible to compile DNX against Lego Mindstorms EV3 processor. I know there is some ARM support and even there are some builds against it ([nuget packages for arm architecture for asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537245/nuget-packages-for-arm-architecture-for-asp-net-5)) but I don't know if there are any differences between ARM processors that would prevent doing this on Lego.

I know that there are projects like lejos that compile java runtime and run it on Lego brick. There is Mono Brick project that runs mono runtime and uses mono libraries. DNX is also open source so I would believe that can be done.

So my question is if DNX currently support this or it would need some serious rewrite?

Can https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/tree/dev/src/dnx.coreclr.unix project be used as a startup point?

I am currently interested only in some very simple implementation runtime that bootstrap a simple .net application on EV3 brick. No sensors are needed.

Comment: I think this would be really cool if you got this working. I don't have any answers for you other than the EV3 has an ARM9 processor that uses the armv5 instruction set. I would recommend checking out http://ev3dev.org and using that as a platform for building on if you try to have a go at implementing this yourself.

Comment: That would be an interesting scenario. I suggest opening a discussion topic on https://github.com/aspnet/dnx

Comment: That's a good idea. I will do it.

Comment: I guess the main issue is to get CoreClr that works on ARM9 on Linux. A version of DNX form ARMv7 (Windows 10 IoT Core - e.g. Raspberry Pi2) actually exists and works. I tried once compiling CoreClr for the original Raspberry Pi (ARM11) but the available tools are out dated. I think cross compiling should work but I have not tried. Once you get CoreClr it shouldn't be too difficult to compile DNX accordingly. Or, if Mono 4.0.x is available you can use that and you won't have to compile DNX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - no there is nothing that prevents it. Moreover it is possible to run DNX on Lego using ev3dev project and mono.

Full description of my struggles can be found here: http://bleedingnedge.com/2015/11/08/asp-net-5-on-lego-mindstorms-ev3-using-ev3dev/

Comment: sadly, link is dead.